# Ruby's YAML.dump not cooperating with circular objects and custom initializers

Tags: ruby, serialization, yaml

Imagine I have this class an I want to serialize its objects with YAML:

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :var, :some_proc

  def initialize
    @var = self
    @some_proc = put_some_important_proc_here
  end
end
```

Clearly, `@some_proc` shouldn't be serialized, so I added this method to only serialize `@var`:

```
def encode_with(coder)
  coder['var'] = @var
end
```

But now I get an stack overflow when I try to serialize this object, because it's just trying to serialize itself again and again without doing that YAML reference magic for circular objects. How can I prevent the `@some_proc` field from getting serialized?

Comment: I fail to see any relation between the error and code you've posted above. Can you be a bit specific about which part of your code isn't co-operating(unless I am missing something)?

Comment: When I try to serialize `Thing.new` using YAML, I get a stack overflow.